# Why 说的 and not only 说 in 你要按照我说的做并且要做好?

Tags: grammar, particles

I saw that phrase while I was studying and I don't understand.

> 你要按照我*说的*做并且要做好。

Why 说的 not only 说?
What does 的 mean in that phrase?

Answer (score 2):

In Chinese, noun phrases in the form:

> nominal modifier + 的 + noun

may drop the noun when:

1. it's clear enough from the context
2. it's a term very generic in meaning

**Clear from the context**

This is the case where a noun is dropped to avoid unnecessary repetition.

> 这本书很有意思，谁写的（书）
>
> This book is very interesting, who wrote **it**? (Who wrote the book)

**Very generic in meaning**

> 你要按照我说的 (话）...

As in your case, the generic nature of the noun may be given by two factors:

1. it's actually a generic term, as 事情 (matter)，东西 (thing), sometimes 人 (person, guy). It can be translated in English as a relative pronoun, e.g. "what":

> 他建议的（事情 / 东西 / 意见），我不太了解
>
> I don't really understand **what** he's suggesting

> 昨天我遇到的（人）就是陈杰最好的朋友
>
> **The person** / **Whom** I met yesterday is actually Chen Jie's best friend

2. it's the object of a [separable verb](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Separable_verb) (because it has a generic unspecified meaning)

> 我每天吃的（饭）是我娘做的（东西）
>
> **The food** / **What** I eat every day is **what** my mum prepares

Answer (score 1):

The context of 我说的 in this sentence could be orders(命令), instructions(指示), teaching(教導), advices(建議), etc. It should go back to previous diaglog to know exactly what 我说的 is.

說 is a verb. It refers to an ACTION. Similar to SAY, SPEAK, TALK, TELL etc.

"你要按照我说的做并且要做好" means I have told you the orders(命令) or instructions(指示) or teaching(教導) or advices(建議) BEFORE. You should follow it and get things perfectly done.